# Поехала верстка в списке вопросов

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Что-то пошло не так?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И еще:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ресурс "голоса" был изменен на "по количеству голосов" похоже. 2 *голоса*, 3 *голоса*, 4 *голоса* и т.д., другие не пострадали, вроде

Comment: так ниже 11 голосов и вроде норм все

Comment: если бы по русски было правильно "11 голоса", то тоже бы поехало :)

Comment: -3 - тоже сломалось

Comment: Ну да, "-3 голоса" же

Comment: ага, не понял первый комментарий просто :-D

Comment: Меня опередили по жалобе насчет "по количеству голосов" :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо за замечание! Обновил строки. После следующей сборки новая строка будет доступна.

Comment: Теперь применение переводов проходит мимо Вас?

Comment: @alexolut Все как и ранее.

Comment: Очень жаль на самом деле. Саморегулирование следующего этапа развития руСО не получится так.

Comment: @alexolut Поясните, пожалуйста. Я не вижу корреляции.

Comment: не видите корреляции саморегулирования с возможностью самостоятельно изменять переводы интерфейса сайта?

Comment: @alexolut Тут вопрос не в саморегулировании, а в технических особенностях реализации. Я обсуждал автоматическую загрузку строк еще несколько лет назад. Пока, как мы видим, данная идея не получила реализации. То есть я с вами полностью согласен, что обновляться должно автоматически, без привязки к структуре сообщества!