# Что творится с переводом?

Tags: обсуждение, локализация

Раньше, как я помню, точные формулировки причин закрытия, тревог и прочего обсуждались здесь, на Мете.

Но теперь пришел новый переводчик и меняет их без обсуждения. Вот свежий пример: [ссылка](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7575/%d0%9e%d0%b1%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b5%d1%80%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d0%b0-%d1%82%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b3-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%8f#comment31156_7576)) - тревога "Более не является необходимым" теперь звучит как "Неуместен или устарел".

Это вообще нормально? Даже если отбросить в сторону "высокие материи" вроде самоуправления, у нас уже есть куча обсуждений по поводу этой тревоги:

[https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q="более не является необходимым"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5+%D0%BD%D0%B5+%D1%8F%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F+%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%85%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D1%8B%D0%BC%22) (10 постов на момент написания вопроса).

Теперь эти 10 постов потеряли смысл. Новичок, решивший их прочитать, уже не поймет о какой именно тревоге речь. Даже самого факта переименования тревоги нет на мете в пригодном для поиска виде.

В какой момент стало возможным для переводчиков вносить в перевод принципиальные изменения без обсуждения?

Comment: Хороший вопрос, Павел!

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371845/ - тревогу переименовали по всей сети :(

Comment: Николас и [представить](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/213987) нового переводчика [не успел](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/46177005#46177005).

Answer (score 11):

У меня была мысль оформить сообщение по поводу локализации в качестве ответа в другой ветке: [Открытое обсуждение проблем сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7567/176217)
Но здесь, наверное, в отдельном вопросе это будет даже актуальнее.

Не так давно, когда у нас [ещё был собственный менеджер сообщества](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7545/176217) неожиданно для многих участников на сайте появился новый переводчик, с возможностью единолично утверждать строки (в терминологии местной системы переводов это называется "корректор" или "reviewer"). После утверждения строк на Transifex, достаточно лишь попросить КМ (или другого сотрудника компании, имеющего доступ к этой возможности), чтобы строки улетели в очередной свежий билд сайта. А так как КМ особо в строки не смотрит (видимо, доверяет корректору или опять таки, нет времени), мы получали и такие приколы как недавно: [Поехала верстка в списке вопросов](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7565/176217)

Я с этим переводчиком немного контактировал ещё до его утверждения в качестве корректора, и всё вроде бы выглядело пристойно. Мы кое-что согласовывали, я утверждал, далее КМ применял переводы. После недавних волнений на ruSO я несколько отошёл от проблем локализации сайта (всё же удовольствия от приведения сайта в порядок несколько меньше получается, когда тебя в чате банят почём зря). Но свято место, видно, пусто не бывает, английские строки обновляются, слетают и т.п., надо с этим было что-то делать. КМ лично времени на это нет, как я понимаю, и он принял решение назначить такого человека. Во времена, когда я [напросился на аналогичную должность](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/4066/176217) КМ консультировался с [VladD](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/10105/vladd) и [Nick Volynkin](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/users/181472/nick-volynkin) (как с действующими корректорами) на предмет моего назначения, тут же всё прошло тихо за закрытыми дверьми. Не знаю, может Nick Volynkin, конечно, и был в курсе, хотя не уверен, т.к. он тоже стал существенно реже на сайте появляться. Ну а почему VladD не спрашивали, я думаю, должно быть и без лишних объяснений понятно.

Не хочу сказать, что новый переводчик просто жуть какой, ошибки случаются со всеми, да и я порой проводил некоторые "локализаторские произволы", но, видимо, мне везло больше. Однако некоторые свежие переводы действительно было бы неплохо обсудить, прежде чем вносить существенные изменения. Первое, что я помню в этой связи, это [переименование знака "Завхоз"](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7493/176217). Неожиданно, но вроде всё разрулилось, даже ответы заплюсовали и стало наверное даже лучше, но всё же менее привычно для старых участников.

Тем не менее, могу высказаться и в защиту переводчика тем фактом, что оригинальные английские строки меняются, Например, то, что раньше было "no longer needed" / "более не является необходимым" стало как раз таки "It's not relevant.", что, вероятно, нуждается и в несколько ином переводе. В целом я не сторонник чрезмерной своевольности в переводах, но иногда без неё не обойтись.

Про оригинальную формулировку "no longer needed" есть большой пост на MSE:
[New "no longer needed" flag reason title is incorrect](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/298507/339911).

Что ещё можно было бы добавить, так это то, что переводчик является по совместительству модератором сайта "Русский язык" и пытается сделать переводы так, чтобы они уместно смотрелись там. Переводы строк для наших сайтов одинаковые (нельзя учесть контекст и сделать альтернативный перевод) и это тоже вносит некоторые проблемы. Хотя в целом, 99% строк, скорее всего должны быть действительно идентичными.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnC0c.jpg

Answer (score 9):

Вопрос хороший. Но для начала мне бы хотелось прокомментировать эмоциональную составляющую этой ситуации.

Первое, на чём хотелось бы заострить внимание - локализация сайта на русский язык **одна** на всю Сеть SE.
На данный момент, у нас есть 2 проекта на русском - это ruSO и «Русский язык». Я надеюсь(в этом я не одинок), что когда-нибудь таких проектов будет больше.
Перевод на всех русскоязычных сайтах Сети должен выглядеть органично, поэтому апелляции к модели мышления разработчика не вполне корректны.

На ресурсе с такой большой аудиторией, не может быть только одного человека, отвечающего за локализацию. До сего момента у нас их **всего** два: alexolut и Aer. Рано или поздно нам придётся научиться командной работе. Здесь нет места ревности.

Второе, переводы - не есть что-то высеченное в камне, при возникновении проблем любого рода, всегда можно всё исправить, обсудить, отменить.
Некорректные с нашей точки зрения изменения могут оказаться обязательными для другого ресурса. Например, если нам, как разработчикам, привычнее/удобнее видеть более лаконичные формулировки пусть даже в ущерб грамотности, то на сайте «Русский язык» поступаться грамотностью никак невозможно. Уверяю Вас, никто не будет тратить своё время на переводы для того, чтобы кому-то насолить.

Любые произведённые изменения могут обсуждаться, но участвовать в обсуждении должны все стороны, и у нас, как у "старшего брата" не должно быть более сильного голоса в этом вопросе. Напротив, кому как не экспертам русской словесности знать все тонкости перевода, который будет "хорош в общем", а не "хорош для сайта программистов"?

И давайте, наконец, научимся слушать друг друга.

---

Теперь по вопросу.

> тревога "Более не является необходимым" теперь звучит как "Неуместен или устарел"

Как верно заметил @alexolut, оригинальный текст тревоги изменился.

@Aer, к слову, сопроводил этот перевод понятным комментарием:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Эти комментарии, доступны в Transifex команде переводчиков.

У нас есть как минимум 2 варианта решения:

- сидеть на привычном, но не вполне корректном переводе(откатить не проблема)
- отредактировать упоминания старого текста тревоги на мете/справке, там, где это необходимо

Подобные мелочи не повод устраивать порку переводчику-добровольцу, вы не находите?
Любая из подобных проблем имеет решение, исключающее столбы позора и публичные казни.

> В какой момент стало возможным для переводчиков вносить в перевод принципиальные изменения без обсуждения?

В тот момент, когда переводчиком стал участник другого русскоязычного сообщества.

Мы можем попросить его согласовывать каждую правку на нашей Мете, увеличив его объём работы на порядок, а можем просто создавать обсуждение изменений, с которыми мы не согласны.

Другой вариант решения всей этой проблемы - требовать от Сети канала локализации для каждого сайта... Думаю понятно, почему это плохое решение?

Comment: Непонятно, почему невоможен отдельный канал локализации. Это единственно правильное решение.

Comment: Т.е., скажем на 15 проектов создавать 15 каналов русского языка? Он у нас что, настолько разный этот язык? 1. зачем дублировать работу? 2. это вредит русскоязычному коммьюнити в целом, разбегаться по своим углам — так себе затея. Но это на мой взгляд.

Comment: Уточню, мне решение плодить каналы локализации не нравится. Но я не утверждаю, что это в принципе невозможно. На мой взгляд, всё обсуждаемо, было бы полезно.

Comment: А почему и нет, в ситуации, когда эти проекты _реально_ требуют разных переводов? Надо 15 — значит, 15. Ну и мы ж программисты, значит, нужно сделать один базовый набор + немногочисленные оверрайды для каждого из подсайтов. Да, это надо запрограммировать. Да, это детская задача.

Comment: @VladD это не проблема локализации. более общая проблема в том, что список типов тревог на комментариях - общий для всей сети. От SO до mythology.stackexchange.com. И если разработчики считаю, что причин теперь не 5, а 3, и что "No longer needed" стоит взять и включить в "It's not relevant." - то это применяется везде. Да, при этом слетает перевод на русский - но переводчик в этом не виноват.

Comment: @VladD на всех остальных сайтах смена типов тревог прилетает в таком же виде - сегодня одни, завтра - другие. Просто они не изолированы языковым барьером, и они могут узнать о смене и обсудить ее до вступления в силу. А мы - нет. Хотя и внезапные смены вызывают возмущение - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/371845/

Comment: @PashaPash: Возможно, это так — напишете пост на Meta.SE, или попросите Николаса, чтобы написал?

Comment: @VladD сорри, я в жестком оффлайне до понедельника (байдарки), так что не успеваю даже разобраться, было ли решение принято на мете или это просто "от создателей движка" пришло :(. спрошу в мод канале, может кто-от из других модераторов поможет

Comment: @PashaPash: Хороших выходных!