# Убрать (а) со страницы службы поддержки

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

На [странице службы поддержки](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact) ruSO в выпадающем списке есть такая причина:

> Я забыл(а) пароль

> [image: Я забыл(а) пароль]

Насколько я знаю, на сайте принято либо использовать упоминание участников в мужском роде, либо в обобщённой форме без таких альтернативных окончания типа "(а)".

Поэтому предлагаю просто убрать это "(а)". Если видите более красивые варианты, предлагайте в ответах с описанием, почему именно так должно быть.

Comment: Вы поосторожней с такими предложениями в нынешних реалиях. Кто-то может и оскорбиться, you know   (¬‿¬ )

Comment: Когда выкатят? )

Comment: @Suvitruf выкатят [статус-*но]?

Comment: Перевод. На странице связи всё ещё "Я забыл(а) пароль".

Comment: @Suvitruf в свете новых обстоятельств надо бы учитывать и справочную страницу, а это только через КМ решается. Но пока я, так и быть, приму вариант AK в традусёре.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вообще-то самый очевидный вариант вполне себе гендерно-нейтрален:

> Я не помню пароль

Comment: Действительно. Надо было поговорить с уточкой перед публикацией :) А ещё такое [любопытное уведомление прилетело](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AY3C8.png).

Comment: @älёxölüt ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Но я потом всё же придумал, что написать в сообщении, чтобы не оставалось этой фразы про слишком короткий пост.

Comment: В истории изменений нет, а во входящих есть.

Answer (score 1):

Ещё как вариант:

> Я хочу восстановить пароль

Comment: Или только лишь его хеш? :)

Comment: Да, по-моему так даже лучше: все варианты с "я хочу" далеко отстоят от этого пункта, рядом только "мне нужно". Кстати, в этом ответе лучше сразу оба варианта перечислить: и "я хочу восстановить пароль" и "мне нужно восстановить пароль", они равноценны.

Comment: @AK но ведь восстановить пароль в современных реализациях не представляется возможным, ибо он не хранится в виде, допускающем его восстановление. Только генерация нового.

Comment: @älёxölüt Да, но оно лучше с точки зрения языка - объясняет что именно человек просит сделать, а не просто "у меня то-то" - на которое вопрос ---"и чо?"--- "ну и?"

Answer (score 1):

Оказывается в справке есть [соответствующий раздел](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/reset-password) и там никаких (а).

> [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Хорошо бы учесть этот момент для единобразия.

Comment: *Чтобы дополнить свой вопрос, просим вас воспользоваться опцией редактирования. Кнопку «Опубликовать ответ» следует использовать только для исчерпывающих ответов на вопросы. :-)*

Comment: @PavelMayorov любой ответ по сути дополняет вопрос. А в данном случае его можно принять к сведению, исправляя перевод. Так-то если подумать, можно было вовсе на Мету не выносить, поменял бы втихую, никто бы и не заметил. Собственно, так довольно много чего меняется :) Главное знать как менять, чтобы было [незаметно](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7579/176217).